The physics behind ceiling fans' rotation sense
Most ceiling fans (especially in hot climates) rotates in an anticlockwise (or 'counterclockwise' if you're American) sense. We all know this. I tried to search the web for a reason why. All I found was some version of this:

Ceiling fans are designed to rotate in a specific direction to maximize their cooling potential. Typically, the fan direction of rotation is anticlockwise, which means the blades spin counterclockwise when viewed from below.
The reason for this rotation direction is simple: it’s designed to create a cooling breeze in the room. When a ceiling fan rotates in an anticlockwise direction, it creates a down draft of air that circulates around the room. This down draft can help to cool the room by circulating the air and creating a wind chill effect.

So, here's my question: why does the anticlockwise rotation ensure that the wind moves downward? What's the reason for the downward force?

Every ceiling fan that I've ever owned (probably close to a dozen of them) has had a switch on it somewhere to control the direction of rotation (i.e., to control whether it moves air up toward the ceiling, or down toward the floor.) During heating season, I want the fan to mix the air in the room so that it's the same temperature everywhere instead of being hotter at the ceiling, and colder at the floor. During cooling season, I want to feel the breeze on my exposed skin. I can't say that I've ever noticed whether the up/down switch made any real difference in either scenario.

To add to naturallyInconsistent's answer...

What's the reason for the downward force?

You really just need to think about the slant of the fan blade and the direction you want to push the air.
For example, if you look head on at the blade and it makes a line with a positive slope, then if the blade moves to your right it will collide with air molecules to its right and give them a downward velocity. You can get the same effect with a blade with a negative slope that moves to your left. These cases respectively correspond to clockwise and counterclockwise rotation when viewing the fan from below.
Reverse only one of either the slant or the rotation direction compared to the above case to have the fan move air upwards.

+1. On the topic of adding more to the answer, the advice for swapping fan directions assumes a lot of stuff. For example, if your ceiling is very high, then the advice doesn't work and you should always just blow directly downwards. If you are eating, you don't want the wind to blow directly at your food, and so you usually want the fan to pull air up weakly rather than blow downwards strongly. It would have been much more useful to just explain the reasons than to state the advice alone.

@naturallyInconsistent, A ceiling fan is useful during heating season to prevent the air from stratifying--cool air down where the people are, warmer air up top. If the ceiling is "very high," then switching the fan to blow upward might be more effective for that purpose. (But, that's not something I've ever tried to measure.)

The websites that you are reading are simply assuming that the blades of your fan are following a convention.
It is the directionality of the fan blades that determines which direction of rotation gets which direction of air flow. You can simply get the opposite fan blade direction and obtain the opposite air flow.

This answer's not enough for me, unfortunately. I'm looking for concrete reasons; not matter-of-fact statements.

FYI, What you called "opposite fan blade direction," would be called "opposite pitch" by engineers who know more than the rest of us about designing fans and turbines and propellers and etc.
